# how to change particular data grid cell properties by the value of cell in c# with Sqlite database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I am new to `c#` and `Database` linking that's why not able to get this by searching old posts of [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

### Code like

```
private void bookDetails()
    {
        string connectionPath = @"Data Source=Data\libraryData.dat;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True";

        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath))
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT bookno as 'Book No.', bookCode as 'ISBN No.', title as 'Title', author as 'Author', publisher as 'Publishers', edition as 'Edition', storagehint as 'Storage Hint', description as 'Description' FROM booksDetails";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "booksDetails");
            int c = ds.Tables["booksDetails"].Rows.Count;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["booksDetails"];
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["ISBN No."], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            connection.Close();
            this.Totals.Text = "Total No. of Books Found : "+ Convert.ToString(c);
        }
    }
```

i used like above for getting some library book details, now i want highlight a particular cell or change its color by the value of no. of book or any other..

sample code preferred

thanks in advance...

Comment: are you using wpf or winforms?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx - for webforms
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(VS.71).aspx - for winforms

Comment: i got answer also, below code is useful to me  thank you @kshitij Mehta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        Color c = Color.Black;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            if (isLate(Convert.ToString(e.Value)))
                c = Color.Red;
        }
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = c; // or e.CellStyle.BackColor= c; whatever you can do like this

    }
```

and code for event is

```
this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

this will be auto generated in `yourform.designer.cs` or else you add it manually

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the rows in the datagridview and then set the color to the appropriate row.

Assuming that the color changes based on some condition,

```
private void myDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
   int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
   int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

   if (rowIndex >= 0 && colIndex >= 0)
   {
    DataGridViewRow myRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    if (myRow.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString() == "High")
    myRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
  }
```

Comment: this also works but i want change cell properties by one of its value, any way thank you